# How to call tableView method directly?

Tags: ios, delegates, tableview

I have a method constructed like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//some table related stuff

}
```

However I cannot call this, so I basically copied and pasted the whole function and renamed as:

```
 - (void)jumpCountry: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//some table related stuff
}
```

and calling this method by using:

`[self jumpCountry:countryIndex];`

However my class looks ugly (and not preferred) because it has got the same two methods. So, how can I call the initial method directly(I know that it is assigned to a button which invokes that method). I am using iOS6.1. Basically, the reason why I want to directly call is I have another thread that listens notifications(from location services), once a notification is received, the table view should be changed. The notification itself already searches for NSIndexPath, so there won't be any problem with that.

Comment: Why can you not call `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: compiler gives an error " Use of undeclared identifier 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' "

Comment: I didn't understand your issue, can you make it clear ? Why you can't call `[self jumpCountry:countryIndex];` from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` , instead of repeating the code ?

Comment: Hmm, I did not think about it. I'll do it now thanks

Comment: Show the code for how you try to call it.

Comment: what do you want to achieve, please explain your question clearly so people will give exact answer.

Comment: I explained now specificly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put

```
[self jumpCountry:countryIndex];
```

to your method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I want to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: from inside or outside of class?

Comment: you can just call that method

Comment: Anyway, for some reason I was not and I totally forgot this simple way. So I think this is the answer for this simple problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method a delegate method of table view from `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and it gets call when user select a row in `UITableView`. you should not call this method by your self.

instead of you can create your method and do whatever you want to do and call it in `viewDidLoad` or any method.

Comment: I know I shouldn't call it but how do I call it anyway?

Comment: what you want do in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method can you please explain @SarpKaya ?

Comment: There isn't really a rule which says you shouldn't call it, so long as you're clear about what you're doing and why (and add a comment so people know in the future).

Comment: @Wain I think Delegates job is to perform task on behalf of other object. so what I personally feel to not interfere in that. if you can want to perform any task,should use some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To call programatically  use

```
[tabelView selectRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Here `scrollIndexPath` is the indexpath of row to be selected

For creating indexpath

```
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```